# Mozilla ThunderBird setHeader(hdr,val) strips multiple spaces

Tags: thunderbird, email-headers, thunderbird-addon

I am developing an addon for Mozilla Thunderbird, and I need to set a custom header on outgoing emails. I have noticed an anomaly in the way headers are set.
The call: `gMsgCompose.compFields.setHeader('x-test', 'multiple  spaces');`

will set the x-test header to: `multiple spaces` - notice how the double spaces were transformed into a single space.

My addon depends on being able to retrieve the exact value, including double spaces. It is not an option to replace double spaces with something else. How can I make Thunderbird stop this transformation? Is the source code available somewhere so I can examine why and how this happens? I suspect the problem might lie with how line folding is implemented.

Cheers.

Comment: Alright, so I found [this](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/82d0a583a9a39bf0b0000bccbf6d5c9ec2596bcc/addon-sdk/source/test/addons/e10s-content/lib/httpd.js#4639) piece of code that "normalizes" the value. Does an effective job of converting all consecutive spaces into a single. Not entirely sure why that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature, apparently. [Here is the source code in question](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/82d0a583a9a39bf0b0000bccbf6d5c9ec2596bcc/addon-sdk/source/test/addons/e10s-content/lib/httpd.js#4639). This is to comply with [RFC-2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) about replacing linear-white-spaces with a single space.

So I guess Thunderbird does as its supposed to, and I have to find another way around that limitation.